# c# menuStrip_ItemClicked

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

which event to use to get the menu strip item clicked?

I've tried the menuStrip_ItemClicked event of the menuStrip; but it fires only on the top menus only ( like "File", "Edit", "Windows").

I want to catch the sub menu items clicked event.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about winforms here?

Comment: Yes I use VS2010, C#, Winforms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about WindowsForms and use VisualStudio:

Go to design of your menu, rigth click on menu item you want, select properties, in property grid select events tab, select Click or MenuClick (don't remember precisely) event and double click on it.

Done

Answer (score 0):

I think you should hook to click event of each ToolStripMenuItem. It can be the done with the same event handler if you prefer to have logic for it in one function.

Comment: So, it's not possible to use a method like:         void menuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.ClickedItem.Name) {
                case "mniLoginLogout":
                    LoginLogout();
                    break;
                case "mniCompany":
                    LaunchCompany();
                    break;}}

Comment: It's possible, you just have to attach  menuStrip_ItemClicked function to click event of all ToolStripMenuItem items

Comment: It is possible, but you have to wire or register that method with the control's event. C# isn't like JavaScript or some other languages where event handlers are attached based on naming convention. If you open your form's designer file you will see that there are event handler assignments defined there.

Comment: I don't think it matters if you have one method that does all in your own switch statement, or if you make all functionality in separate methods (which is a nicer design pattern I think).

Answer (score 0):

Every subitem has its own event for clicking. In the winforms designer, you can just double click on the correct item you want to let happen. It will create a `saveButton_clicked` event or whatever event you would like and you can specify the information for that specific action in the method.

You can even let the shortcut commands work like `CTRL+S` when assigning them in the designer of visual studio.